# Loop to download worldmet data in R

Tags: r, for-loop, index

I'm rather new to R. I am trying to create a loop to download worldmet data for each uk weather station for a particular year. I have found a previous link but still unable to get the required output - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63394191/creating-a-loop-to-download-and-write-met-data-to-csv/73988018?noredirect=1#comment130638650_73988018

I have a .csv file whoch list all the sites and codes as shown below (called UK_NOAA)

```
code          station                ctry
037760-99999  GATWICK                UK
037690-99999  CHARLWOOD              UK
038760-99999  SHOREHAM               UK
038820-99999  HERSTMONCEUX WEST END  UK
037810-99999  BIGGIN HILL            UK
```

I have used the previous code in the link to create a loop.

```
Startyear <- "2011"
Endyear <- "2011"

Yearlist <- seq(as.numeric(Startyear), as.numeric(Endyear))

for(i in 1:nrow(siteinfo)){
  for(j in 1:length(Yearlist)){
    importNOAA(code=siteinfo$code[i],year=Yearlist[j],hourly = TRUE)
  }}
```

However the ImportNOAA function (below) requires the 'code' to be imported with " " surrounding the site code.

```
met_uk  <- importNOAA(code = "034185-99999", year = 2011, hourly = FALSE)
```

Therefore, I import function does not recognise the inputs from the csv and i receive this error message...

**Missing data for site 30020-99999 and year 2011
[1] "site(s) do not exist".**

Could anybody help?

Comment: Which package does the `importNOAA` function come from?

Comment: The 'worldmet' package - https://github.com/davidcarslaw/worldmet

Comment: This: `Missing data for site 30020-99999 and year 2011 [1] "site(s) do not exist".` looks like its chopped a leading zero from the site code. How did you read the `siteinfo` from the `CSV` file? Does it have the leading zero? That site code works if I add the leading zero...

Comment: I shall look into this now! Look like the whole csv is like this. I downloaded the csv from the website. If this is the case I shall post a comment.

Comment: I'm guessing its been through Excel at some point which decided they were numbers...